# Ошибка hibernate java: cannot find symbol symbol: variable goods

Tags: java, hibernate

В файле main/java/DAO/ShopDAOImpl.java в запросе `session.createQuery` возникает ошибка "cannot find symbol symbol: variable goods", хотя класс goods есть - описан в файле shop.good.java. Проект можно посмотреть здесь: https://github.com/Pir-Anya/shopserver. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

```
package DAO;

import shop.category;
import shop.goods;
import util.HibernateUtil;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import util.HibernateUtil;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Query;


public class ShopDAOImpl  implements ShopDAO{

    // public void deleteBus(Bus bus) throws SQLException;
    public Collection getGoodsByCategory(category cat) throws SQLException{
        Session session = null;
        List list_goods = new ArrayList<goods>();
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            int cat_id = cat.getId();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from goods where category_id = :cat_id").setLong("cat_id", cat_id);
            list_goods = (List<goods>) query.list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return goods;
    };
}
```

Класс goods:

```
    package shop;


public class goods {
    private int id;
    private int id_category;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId_category() {
        return id_category;
    }

    public void setId_category(int id_category) {
        this.id_category = id_category;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так покажите stacktrace, класс покажите.
Работает ли это без условия where ?

Comment: покажите как описали класс  goods

Comment: Без условия where не работает, подчеркивает красным goods в этой строке еще даже без компиляции: Query query = session.createQuery("from goods where category_id = :cat_id").setLong("cat_id", cat_id);

Answer (score 0):

1. Маппинг класса есть в файле `hibernate.cfg.xml`?
2. Если таблицы нет в базе то она создается? (Значения свойства `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`должны быть либо `create`, либо `create-drop`, либо `update`.
3. Попробуйте использовать имя базы при обращении к таблице в запросе таким образом: `db_name.shop`.

А вообще было бы не плохо увидеть код класса и содержимое файла `hibernate.cfg.xml`, а то советы "вслепую" получаются.

Comment: 1. Да маппинг прописан в hibernate.cfg.xml. 2. Таблицы в базе есть. 3. Попробовала, но это не помогло